# Generic function taking a type name in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

In C#, it's possible to call a generic method by specifying the type:

```
public T f<T>()
{
   return something as T
}

var x = f<string>()
```

Swift doesn't allow you to specialize a generic method when calling it. The compiler wants to rely on type inference, so this is not possible:

```swift
func f<T>() -> T? {
    return something as T?
}

let x = f<String>() // not allowed in Swift
```

What I need is a way to pass a type to a function and that function returning an object of that type, using generics

This works, but it's not a good fit for what I want to do:

```swift
let x = f() as String?
```

**EDIT (CLARIFICATION)**

I've probably not been very clear about what the question actually is, it's all about a simpler syntax for calling a function that returns a given type (any type).

As a simple example, let's say you have an array of Any and you create a function that returns the first element of a given type:

```swift
// returns the first element in the array of that type
func findFirst<T>(array: [Any]) -> T? {
    return array.filter() { $0 is T }.first as? T
}
```

You can call this function like this:

```swift
let array = [something,something,something,...]

let x = findFirst(array) as String?
```

That's pretty simple, but what if the type returned is some protocol with a method and you want to call the method on the returned object:

```swift
(findFirst(array) as MyProtocol?)?.SomeMethodInMyProtocol()
(findFirst(array) as OtherProtocol?)?.SomeMethodInOtherProtocol()
```

That syntax is just awkward. In C# (which is just as strongly typed as Swift), you can do this:

```
findFirst<MyProtocol>(array).SomeMethodInMyProtocol();
```

Sadly, that's not possible in Swift.

So the question is: **is there a way to accomplish this with a cleaner (less awkward) syntax.**

Comment: someFunc() goes looking for an object of the type provided and returns it. It's as simple as that. I wanted to provide the minimum amount of information required because the specifics and the "why" are irrelevant.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Please can you clarify your question. You say that `T` can be any protocol, but you cannot create an instance of a protocol. Protocols are abstract – you can only ever create an instance of a *concrete* type that conforms to a given protocol. The "specifics" are definitely relevant to this question. I'm not sure if you're trying to compare a function output with a given type, and only return it if it conforms to that type – or if you're trying to create a fresh instance of a given type you pass in.

Comment: I don't need to create an instance. The function will look somewhere for objects conforming to that protocol and then return it. No new objects need to be created.

Comment: I've updated my question. I realize it's not as clear as it could be

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot explicitly define the type of a generic function (by using the `<...>` syntax on it). However, you *can* provide a generic metatype (`T.Type`) as an  *argument* to the function in order to allow Swift to infer the generic type of the function, as [Roman has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216835/2976878).

For your specific example, you'll want your function to look something like this:

```
func findFirst<T>(in array: [Any], ofType _: T.Type) -> T? {
  return array.lazy.compactMap { $0 as? T }.first
}
```

Here we're using `compactMap(_:)` in order to get a sequence of elements that were successfully cast to `T`, and then `first` to get the first element of that sequence. We're also using `lazy` so that we can stop evaluating elements after finding the first.

Example usage:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
  func doSomething()
}

protocol AnotherProtocol {
  func somethingElse()
}

extension String : SomeProtocol {
  func doSomething() {
    print("success:", self)
  }
}

let a: [Any] = [5, "str", 6.7]

// Outputs "success: str", as the second element is castable to SomeProtocol.
findFirst(in: a, ofType: SomeProtocol.self)?.doSomething()

// Doesn't output anything, as none of the elements conform to AnotherProtocol.
findFirst(in: a, ofType: AnotherProtocol.self)?.somethingElse()
```

Note that you have to use `.self` in order to refer to the metatype of a specific type (in this case, `SomeProtocol`). Perhaps not a slick as the syntax you were aiming for, but I think it's about as good as you're going to get.

Although it's worth noting in this case that the function would be better placed in an extension of `Sequence`:

```
extension Sequence {
  func first<T>(ofType _: T.Type) -> T? {
    // Unfortunately we can't easily use lazy.compactMap { $0 as? T }.first
    // here, as LazyMapSequence doesn't have a 'first' property (we'd have to
    // get the iterator and call next(), but at that point we might as well
    // do a for loop)
    for element in self {
      if let element = element as? T {
        return element
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
}

let a: [Any] = [5, "str", 6.7]
print(a.first(ofType: String.self) as Any) // Optional("str")
```

Comment: This is **exactly** the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Although this syntax is even more awkward than the one I came up with, it is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Happy to help :)

Comment: The following works for me in a playground:

class Dummy<T> {
    func cast(_ param: Any) -> T? {
        return param as? T
    }
}

let dummy = Dummy<Double>()
print(dummy.cast(1.0)) // Prints "Optional(1.0)"
print(dummy.cast("")) // Prints "nil"

Comment: Darn; can newlines be inserted into comments?

Comment: Afraid not @Verticon :/

Comment: Thx @Hamish. Nonetheless, can you see the code in the comment well enough to ascertain that it appears to contradict your answer: "Unfortunately, you cannot explicitly define the type of a generic function (by using the <...> syntax on it)."?

Comment: @Verticon I don't think it does – you're using the `<...>` syntax on a generic type there, not on the function itself (and the `cast(_:)` method in your example doesn't have any generic placeholders to satisfy).

Comment: @Hamish Ohhh ... I see now. Explicit specialization can be used when instantiating classes but not when invoking functions.

Comment: @Verticon Yeah exactly, it's only applicable to generic types, not generic functions – it's a weird inconsistency in the language (really, I think you *should* be able to explicitly specialise generic functions with the `<...>` syntax).

Comment: @Hamish what about `for element in self where element is T {
            return element as? T
        }` Does it make a difference performance wise?

Comment: @LeoDabus Shouldn't be too much of a difference performance wise; though you could eliminate the double check with `for case let element as T in self { return element }`. However I went with the if statement just for clarity (looks a bit weird having a for loop body that just immediately returns).

Answer (score 4):

What you probably need to do is create a protocol that looks something like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    init()
    func someProtocolMethod()
}
```

And then add `T.Type` as a parameter in your method:

```
func f<T: SomeProtocol>(t: T.Type) -> T {
    return T()
}
```

Then assuming you have a type that conforms to `SomeProtocol` like this:

```
struct MyType: SomeProtocol {
    init() { }
    func someProtocolMethod() { }
}
```

You can then call your function like this:

```
f(MyType.self).someProtocolMethod()
```

Like others have noted, this seems like a convoluted way to do what you want. If you know the type, for example, you could just write:

```
MyType().someProtocolMethod()
```

There is no need for `f`.

Comment: Of course, f() does something, so I would need f() :-)

Comment: T is not a protocol. T is a Type. You can't instantiate a protocol. You can only instantiate types. The `f` method that you wrote only returns an object. We can only go off of the information in the question :)

Comment: I never said anything about instantiating a new object. The function returns an existing object that conforms to the given protocol.  I've updated my question to make it a little clearer.