# How to pass a Swift type as a method argument?

Tags: types, parameters, swift2

I'd like to do something like this:

```
func doSomething(a: AnyObject, myType: ????)
{
   if let a = a as? myType
   {
       //…
   }
}
```

In Objective-C the class of class was `Class`

Comment: You'll want to use generics with a method input of type `T.Type`, you can then cast to `T` – see for example [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216240/generic-function-taking-a-type-name-in-swift)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You have to use a generic function where the parameter is only used for type information so you cast it to `T`:

```
func doSomething<T>(_ a: Any, myType: T.Type) {
    if let a = a as? T {
        //…
    }
}

// usage
doSomething("Hello World", myType: String.self)
```

---

#### Using an initializer of the type `T`

You don’t know the signature of `T` in general because `T` can be any type. So you have to specify the signature in a protocol.

For example:

```
protocol IntInitializable {
    init(value: Int)
}
```

With this protocol you could then write

```
func numberFactory<T: IntInitializable>(value: Int, numberType: T.Type) -> T {
    return T.init(value: value)
}

// usage
numberFactory(value: 4, numberType: MyNumber.self)
```

Comment: how I call the constructor?

Comment: @Augusto Please see my updated answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Let me explain my problem: I have a Database with some tables, for each table I have a class ( for each object, like product, person, customers...) I wants create a generic function to read all records from database, because this I want use the T (type class) for create a list of these objects. I don't know how I set the type class to create a new object. My constructors receive a dictonary of attributes like parameter.

Comment: @Augusto I think "Rob" answered it perfectly in your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49577256/4780031 which is almost my example.