# Generic Typing Swift, Using T as Type Parser

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types

So I have class named Response

```
class Response<T where T:NSObject>{
    var message:String = ""
    var result:T?
    var status:Int = 0

    init(setMessage message:String, setResult result:T?, setStatus status:Int) {
        self.message = message;
        self.result = result
        self.status = status
    }

    required init(){
        super.init()
    }

    init(JSON:AnyObject, result:T?) {
        self.message = JSON["message"] as! String
        self.result = result
        self.status = JSON["status"] as! Int
    }   
}
```

I want to do another init() where I set the self.result's type as either NSArray or NSDictionary and I've been experimenting with some code and I can't seem to get what I want to do

I want to make something like

```
init(JSON:AnyObject, resultType:T) {
    self.message = JSON["message"] as! String
    self.result = JSON["result"] as? T
    self.status = JSON["status"] as! Int
}
```

And then Call it from another class like

```
let json = //some kind of JSON
Response(JSON: json, resultType:NSArray)
//or
Response(JSON: json, resultType:NSDictionary)
```

Comment: You can use the metatype `T.Type` as your `resultType:`'s type, and then pass in types using the `.self` postfix (e.g `Response(JSON: json, resultType: NSArray.self)`) – see for example [Generic function taking a type name in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216240/generic-function-taking-a-type-name-in-swift). Although as a side note, I would *highly* recommend using native Swift collection types over `NSArray` & `NSDictionary`.

Comment: See the problem is an error shows 
    init<T>(JSON:AnyObject, resultType:T.Type) {
        self.message = JSON["message"] as! String
        self.result = JSON["message"] as! T
        self.status = JSON["status"] as! Int
    } 
when I do this it says "cannot assign value of type T to type _?"

Comment: Remove the `<T>` from `init<T>`, that defines a new generic placeholder – you want to use the class generic placeholder instead.

Comment: oh good God. why didn't I see that. Thank you very much, I've been a little stuck with this code for days now. I actually just wanted to do this cause I'd be shortening my code by a lot. basically my earlier mistake was init(JSON:AnyObject, result:T) this and not using T.Type as the Parameter Type