# Can you both find a first instance of a type in a collection, returning that instance as that concrete type?

Tags: swift, casting, flatmap

This code bothers me. Below, I'm trying to find the first instance of a specific type of ViewController in a NavigationController's stack. Simple.  But when I've found it, I have to then cast it to the type I just looked for, which seems redundant to me.

```
func popToFirstViewController<T:UIViewController>(ofType type:T.Type, animated:Bool) -> T? {

    guard let foundViewController = viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is T }) as? T else {
        return nil
    }

    self.popToViewController(foundViewController, animated:animated)

    return foundViewController
}
```

Only thing I can think of is this...

```
func popToFirstViewController<T:UIViewController>(ofType type:T.Type, animated:Bool) -> T? {

    guard let foundViewController = viewControllers.flatMap({ $0 as? T }).first() else {
        return nil
    }

    self.popToViewController(foundViewController, animated:animated)

    return foundViewController
}
```

...but I've repeatedly found using `flatMap` like this tends to confuse people reading the code, and, as correctly pointed out in the comments below, iterates over the entire collection whereas `first` doesn't do that.

So is there another way to solve this issue?

Comment: You could write always write an extension, see for example the implementation at the bottom of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37217494/2976878

Comment: The bigger problem with using `flatMap` for this is that it iterates through the whole array for no reason, while `first(where:)` enables early exit from the function.

Comment: Very good point that I keep forgetting.  Added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *case patterns* to select the viewControllers of the type you are interested in and pop and return the first one you find:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func popToFirstViewController<T:UIViewController>(ofType type:T.Type, animated:Bool) -> T? {

        for case let vc as T in viewControllers {
            self.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
            return vc
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

---

**Example:**

Use a button in `OrangeViewController` to return to `GreenViewController` earlier in the stack:

```
@IBAction func popToGreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
     let greenVC = self.navigationController?.popToFirstViewController(
           ofType: GreenViewController.self,
         animated: true
     )

     // Modify a property in GreenViewController that
     // will be moved into a label in viewWillAppear      
     greenVC?.labelText = "Returned here from Orange"
}
```

---

**`popToLastViewController(ofType:animated:)`**

You might also want a function to pop to the most recent viewController of a type.  That is easily achieved with a simple modification (adding `.reversed()`):

```
func popToLastViewController<T:UIViewController>(ofType type:T.Type, animated: Bool) -> T? {

    for case let vc as T in viewControllers.reversed() {
        self.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
        return vc
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I originally thought this was the same as `for vc in viewControllers where vc is T` but I just realized doing it this way, vc is already of type T.  I like this a lot!  Thanks!  If something better doesn't come along, this will get marked as the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216240/generic-function-taking-a-type-name-in-swift/37217494#comment85331430_37217494

Comment: You could add an enum parameter to select first vs. last, but I like the clarity of having it in the function name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of combining `flatMap` and [`lazy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687859-lazy) to get the behavior of conditionally casting to `T`, stripping out mismatches, and *not* enumerating the whole array:

```
func popToFirstViewController<T:UIViewController>(ofType type:T.Type, animated:Bool) -> T? {
    guard let foundViewController = viewControllers.lazy.flatMap({ $0 as? T }).first {
        return nil
    }

    self.popToViewController(foundViewController, animated:animated)
    return foundViewController
}
```

As for "confusing people that read the code:" `flatMap` is fairly idiomatic Swift, and will be less ambiguous with the [upcoming rename to `compactMap`](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/replacing-flatmap-with-compactmap/). If readers in your environment really have trouble, you could always write a small helper (generic or not) that performs the same work under a clearer name.

Comment: More details in [my own blog post](http://www.timekl.com/blog/2017/05/14/swift-tricks-searching-for-objects-by-type/) on this.

Comment: +1 for the info on lazy.flatMap. Didn't even know there was an option like that.  Definitely will be checking out your post tomorrow (later today.)  Thanks for the info!

Comment: And good god!  Yet another person with a crazy high rep!  I swear I'm on here all the time posting and I'm struggling to get to 10k! You're at 49k and vacawama is at 76k! I have no idea how you can get that high! Color me impressed!

Comment: +10 for introducing me to the phrase 'nerd sniping'!!  I think that XKCD needs a permanent place on my wall at work!